# Euro modules, is there an actual standard for them? or are they just a de-facto thing?

Tags: electrical, uk

In the UK over the last decade or so a system of modules and faceplaces known as "Euro modules" seems to have taken off. Modules and faceplates are available from a wide-range of vendors. A regular "single" module is 25x50mm and there are also double-width 50x50 modules. The modules clip into a faceplate, with a "single gang" UK plate holding two modules and a "double gang" UK plate holding four modules.

Nearly all data outlets in the UK now use this format and an increasing range of other modules are becoming available. Initially it only seemed to be data/av/telecoms stuff, but mains stuff is now also available (though not common, the vast majority of mains stuff in the UK is still non-modular).

Is there an actual standard for these modules or is it just a de-facto thing? Are they used in other parts of Europe (the name and some pictures i've seen online suggests they are) and if-so what are they known as there)?

Comment: Like these? https://www.legrand.fr/catalogue/interrupteurs-et-prises/mosaic

Comment: You really need to be more specific both on what you are asking and your location . A photo would even help more.  in the U.S. rj45 keystone modules or connectors are the standard I think I have seen single gang faceplates that can handle 6 and double gang that can handle 12. Just google keystone faceplate this is the standard in the US for rj45 connectors and has been for ~30 years.

Comment: 25x50? Why they're practically throwing an insult across the channel, snubbing perfectly fine, round units like 25.4 x 50.8 mm!   Also the prices... wow...

Comment: @EdBeal Euromodules are a specific size (whether actual standard or not I don't know either) rectangular face plates that then have a keystone, flush port(s), brush plate, are blank, etc. Brilliant for modularity and only changing what you need to, or reserving future space (with blanks) - you just install pattress/back box, and a euromodule faceplate however many X units wide, and then you can install X euromodules or a combination of single/double/triple/etc. width until you hit X.

Comment: Best I can find is this datasheet from MK Electric (manufacturer of, among other things, 'Euro' faceplates & modules) that says 'industry standard (Euro) snapfit': https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2363681.pdf - which doesn't really hint one way more than the other. I can't find it on https://www.en-standard.eu/iec-standards/

Comment: They look like standard keystone devices, I thought we were talking about a cover plate as I think the size of the connectors will be the same, I have data equipment from several other countries. This is why I asked, the peach panels look identical to mine.

Comment: Euro modules are MUCH larger than keystones.

Comment: Also you can get keystone Euro modules, one or two per 1U module. I just accidentally posted a duplicate at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566405/is-there-a-published-standard-for-euro-modules forgetting that I'd commented on this question here..